# Why batch script variable remain unchanged inside FOR loop?

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7, windows-nt

We need to control a daemon like `start`, `stop`, `restart`, `status` using batch script where `CKI_SYSTEM_STAT` is variable, changed dynamically base on the condition of the daemon. Here we have to simulate it for your realization according to the issue. `CKI_SYSTEM_STAT` changed randomly, but inside the `for` loop it remain unchanged under `stop` label.

For this reason we are unable to detect either the daemon stopped successfully when stop operation performed. Here is the batch script for your kind consideration.

```
rem ebisd.bat

@echo off
if "%OS%" == "Windows_NT" setlocal
set "CKI_OPTION_NAME=%1"

call :init_ebis
call :ebis_case
goto :eof

:init_ebis
rem initialization of varible
if "%CKI_DAEMON_NAME%" == "" set "CKI_DAEMON_NAME=Demon"
goto :eof

rem fetch the process info
:init_meta
rem init flag
SET /A CKI_RANDOM_NUMB=%RANDOM%%%10
echo Random Number %CKI_RANDOM_NUMB%
if %CKI_RANDOM_NUMB% lss 7 (
  set "CKI_SYSTEM_STAT=stoped"
) else (
  set "CKI_SYSTEM_STAT=runing"
)
goto :eof


:ebis_case
rem label ebis_case
call :init_meta
set "CKI_SWITCH_CASE=false"
for %%i in (start stop status restart) do (
  if %%i'==%CKI_OPTION_NAME%' SET "CKI_SWITCH_CASE=true"
)
if "%CKI_SWITCH_CASE%" == "false" call :message
if "%CKI_SWITCH_CASE%" == "true"  call :case_%CKI_OPTION_NAME%
goto :eof


:case_start
rem label case_start
call :start
goto :eof


:case_stop
rem label case_stop
call :stop
goto :eof


:case_status
rem label case_status
call :status
goto :eof


:case_restart
rem label case_restart
call :restart
goto :eof


:start
rem label start
if "%CKI_SYSTEM_STAT%" == "runing" (
  echo %CKI_DAEMON_NAME% already %CKI_SYSTEM_STAT%
)

if "%CKI_SYSTEM_STAT%" == "stoped" (
  echo %CKI_DAEMON_NAME% is starting
)
goto :eof


:status
rem label status
echo %CKI_DAEMON_NAME% is %CKI_SYSTEM_STAT%
goto :eof


rem label stop
:stop
if "%CKI_SYSTEM_STAT%" == "stoped" (
  echo %CKI_DAEMON_NAME%    %CKI_SYSTEM_STAT%
)

if "%CKI_SYSTEM_STAT%" == "runing" (
  echo %CKI_DAEMON_NAME%   stoping
  for /L %%a in (0,1,5) do (
    call :init_meta
    call :status
    if %%a lss 5 (
      if "%CKI_SYSTEM_STAT%" == "runing" (
        timeout 3 > NUL
        echo Wrong is %CKI_SYSTEM_STAT%
        echo .
      )
      if "%CKI_SYSTEM_STAT%" == "stoped" (
        echo stoped
        goto :eof
      )
    )
    if %%a equ 10 (
      echo unable to  stop
    )
  )
)
goto :eof


:restart
rem label restart
call :stop
call :start
goto :eof


rem label message
:message
echo Usage^: start^|stop^|^status^|restart
goto :eof


:freeze
rem label freeze
@pause
goto :eof
```

For your realization I simulated it by calling the `status` label inside the loop to see the actual value of `CKI_SYSTEM_STAT` also echo the value of `CKI_SYSTEM_STAT` inside `for` loop under `stop` label. But `CKI_SYSTEM_STAT` remain unchanged inside the `for` loop. Here is the console output:

```
c:>batch\ebisd.bat stop
Random Number 8
Demon   stoping
Random Number 2
Demon is stoped
Wrong is runing
.
Random Number 4
Demon is stoped
Wrong is runing
.
Random Number 8
Demon is runing
Wrong is runing
.
Random Number 9
Demon is runing
Wrong is runing
.
Random Number 4
Demon is stoped
Wrong is runing
.
Random Number 4
Demon is stoped
```

There might be mistake inside the script or unable to realize the scope of variable. It would be appreciable if anybody help us to find out the issue/bug of this script. Alternative solution highly expected.

Comment: Have you had a look into [Delayed Expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)?

Comment: @Mofi I think this is applicable of beeing an answer ;) Impressive timing btw :)

Comment: Thanks a lots Mr. [Mofi](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3074564/mofi) . Your solution is`if "%OS%" == "Windows_NT" setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion` and `if "!MSC_SYSTEM_STAT!" == "runing"` is very much exciting and resolve the issue.